# JS die roll simulation with 6 die images

Tags: javascript

in Js, I want to try to simulate a die roll by showing images of die 1 to 6, but when I try to display these in a for loop, it only displays image dice6. I tried putting in a nested for loop to slow down the outer loop but that didnt work. Does the page need to refresh after changing "src" attribute?

```
const dieImage = function (num) {
      return "images/dice" + String(num).trim() + ".png";
    };

function dieRoll(num) {
        
          for (let i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
            for (let z = 0; z < 44444; z++) {} // attempt to slow
        
            if (num === 1) {
              img1.setAttribute("src", dieImage(i));
            } else {
              img2.setAttribute("src", dieImage(i));
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: That won't really slow anything down; if you want a delay, use asynchronous code

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Comment: Besides that a JS engine could just optimize the empty loop right out, computers count pretty fast. Consider using a timeout that updates the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can use `setTimeout`. You can introduce a delay and give the browser a chance to redraw by using `setTimeout`, promise, and `await`, for example like this:

```
const DELAY = 300; // 300ms

async function dieRoll(num) {
  for (let i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    if (num === 1) {
      img1.setAttribute("src", dieImage(i));
    } else {
      img2.setAttribute("src", dieImage(i));
    }

    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), DELAY));
  }
}
```

The loop execution will stop until the promise is resolved, but it will let the browser to continue to respond and redraw. When the promise is resolved after the timeout callback is run after the given `DELAY` milliseconds, the next iteration of the loop will take place.

Comment: Thank you. Works very nicely. One issue I have. After Player1 clicks their die to "roll" the die, I want to change a heading to "Player 2 - click your die!" but that displays immediately, while the async dieRoll function is still changing images. Even if I put that into the async function. Also, after player2 clicks their die, I want to change a heading to show who won, but that heading is displaying before the die images completes. Is there a way to delay code execution until images have finished?

Comment: Yes, just also do `await` on `dieRoll` before changing heading. Then the heading will change only after the roll is completed.

Comment: Bingo! thanks. All working nicely.                                                                           `const DELAY = 200; // 200ms
async function dieRoll(player) {
  const rndNum = randomNumber();
  for (let i = 1; i < 11 + rndNum; i++) {
    showDie(player, (i % 6) + 1);
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), DELAY));
  }
  document.querySelector("h2").innerHTML = "Player 2 - Click your die!";
  if (player === 2) showWinner();
}`

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing (roughly) is that the browser paints the screen when the JavaScript code has finished running. Even though you are setting the `src` attribute to a different image in a loop, the JavaScript code finishes only when the loop ends. The browser paints only once, i.e. the last image you set in the loop. This explanation may be oversimplified, but it gives you an idea.

The solution is to return from the JavaScript code after setting the `src` and repeating after a suitable delay, giving the user the opportunity to sense the change. `setTimeout` is probably good enough for your case; in other use cases where you want really smooth animation, there would be other solutions (e.g. `requestAnimationFrame()`). An untested implementation to demonstrate the intent:

```js
function dieRoll(selectedNum) {
  var counter = 8; // how many times to change the die
  function repeat() {
    if (counter === 1) {
      // on the last iteration, set the image representing the selected number
      img1.setAttribute("src", dieImage(selectedNum));
    } else {
      // else decrement the counter, set a random image and repeat after a timeout
      counter--;
      img1.setAttribute("src", dieImage(Math.floor(6 * Math.random()) + 1));
      setTimeout(repeat, 300);
    }
  }
  repeat();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nikos. I went with the async function and was able to get the result I wanted.